# ADFS 2.0 and Dynamics CRM 2011 SSL for what domain?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, adfs, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have read that the best practice for an IFD Dynamics deployment is to use ADFS2.0 and lock it down with a wildcard SSL Certificate.

The domain name I want to use for the Dynamics deployment is not the same as my Active Directory forest.  I want Dynamics to work with my companies .com address instead of the .net we use for Active Directory.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. The AD domain name is irrelevant and has no impact.

Does the video at this blog answer your questions? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/01/13/configuring-ifd-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx